# Authenticating desktop users for remote API

Tags: c#, authentication, desktop

I have a RESTful API which is running in a Linux docker image on AWS ECS. This API needs to be called by a desktop application (C# fat client deployed via ClickOnce) which is using Windows authentication to identify the users.

Currently although it's behind our firewall I can't identify users who call the API. I looked into OIDC but it's not an option because it requires a redirect URI to callback with the access_token which can't really happen on a desktop application.

How can I identify the users who are calling the API from their desktop app and validate they have the correct group claim which would grant them access when calling the API?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of considering OIDC as an option; depending upon your set-up, I would have thought that you should be able to embed a browser (/WebView) like User-Agent within your desktop app, that can then/finally pass-back the resulting OIDC info/tokens, back to the/your hosting/underlying app (?).